# Why is this method deprecated ? (jasperreports)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, deprecated

Can any one tell me why the `setValueClass` method of `JRDesignExpression` is deprecated ?
Is there any other method I could use instead ?

Comment: This is a question for a developers of JR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was deprecated because the field `valueClass` was deprecated from its superclass [`JRBaseExpression`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/4.1.1/jasperreports-4.1.1-javadoc.jar!/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/base/JRBaseExpression.html)  The field was removed so they do not need the set methods anymore for the field.  There is no explanation as to why on any of the sites.  Someone asked on the jaspersoft forum and the response they got was "because it wasn't needed anymore."

Answer (score 3):

The expression value class attribute was used as expressions expected type.  It worked differently depending on the report expression language.  Java reports failed if an expression did not evaluate to a value that was compatible with the expression type (as in instanceof), while Groovy reports used Groovy casts/conversions to attempt to convert the evaluated value to the expected type.

For Java reports, specifying expression value classes was rather repetitive (e.g. if you had a text field showing an integer value you needed to set the text field expression class to Integer or Number).  On the other hand, the Groovy casts had some unexpected consequences in a few cases.

Therefore the value class attribute of expressions was deprecated in the sense that the need to set it was removed.  All code that evaluates expressions no longer needs to know an expected type in advance, the expressions are evaluated and the caller decides at runtime how to deal with the result of the expression depending on its type.

This means that in most cases calls to setValueClass should be simply removed.  Only if you relied on Groovy casts to convert evaluated values to other types you'd need to include the casts in the expressions themselves.

Comment: +1. I Never thought about the Groovy aspect. Thanks for the enlightenment :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason given on why it is depreciated in the [**API**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignExpression.html). Also sadly there is no other method listed that can replace it.

Please see the same question asked in the JasperSoft community forum in the link below...

[**JRDesignExpression setValueClass deprecated**](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/539887/jrdesignexpression-setvalueclass-deprecated)

Comment: Yeah, I saw this entry on the jasperforum, but the answers given there weren't satisfactory, thus I tried it here. Anyway,thank you neo

Answer (score 1):

I got it. If you open an JRXml file it become obvious.
The type/class you set for a field are not defined in the expression tag

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{myVar}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

but in the field:

```
<field name="myVar" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

So now you can set the type through using the method `setValueClass` of `JRDesignField`.

For example,
you create the field and give it a type:

```
        JRDesignField field = myCreateField();
        field.setValueClass(java.lang.String.class);
```